# Scrolling problem in bootstrap modal: only when using the fade class

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have spent a number of hours debugging this problem. Here is what I am doing:

- I open a bootstrap modal
- From within that modal, I open another modal (I use the data-dismiss attribute to ensure the existing modal is closed first)
- If the second modal is very large and requires scrolling, then this fails. Instead of scrolling the modal, the background scrolls.

Code used for opening the new modal from within the existing modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#modal2">Open modal 2</button>
```

What I have found out is that the problem occurs when I apply the "modal fade" class to the modal. If I remove the "fade" class then it all works well! But I would really like to use the fade class. Is this supposed to be like this? Or is there a workaround? Below a full working example:

```css
.modal-body {
      height: 1000px
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>

  <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">Open modal</button>

  <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#modal2">Open modal 2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#modal1">Open modal 1</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.modal-body {
      height: 1000px
    }
    #modal2{
      overflow-y:auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">Open modal</button>

  <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#modal2">Open modal 2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#modal1">Open modal 1</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If you are talking about workaround here, then you can do something like this

```
#modal2{
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vikasguptaa9/28oc5sem/2/)

Comment: Thanks but this does not seem to work. Scrolling down is still impossible in modal2.

Comment: [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/585936/user), Please check the fiddle one more time. or check the snippet, I have created

Comment: Great, it now works! As you say this is a workaround... is this a bug I should report to Bootstrap? Or is this expected behavior?